# Recursos no encontrados en página alojada en github pages

Tags: html, github-pages

Tengo un problema al desplegar una simple página para testear en *github pages*.

No me reconoce el archivo javascript ni algunas imágenes.

En consola me arroja el siguiente error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () main.js:1

¿Alguna sugerencia de qué debería hacer?

https://github.com/lucaspieran/lucaspierandrei

Comment: Tienes un problema con las rutas. Ahora te explico.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema con las rutas de ambos recursos que te están fallando. En ambos usas una ruta absoluta, cuando deberías haber usado correctamente una ruta relativa.

Te he creado una solicitud de fusión o extracción (*merge* o *pull request*) para solucionar los problemas:

- https://github.com/lucaspieran/lucaspierandrei/pull/1
- https://github.com/lucaspieran/lucaspierandrei/pull/1/files

---

Empecemos por partes.

Tu página está publicada en:

- https://lucaspieran.github.io/lucaspierandrei/

Archivos que dan error:

- `work2.jpg`
- `Personalizado – 2.svg`

Explicación detallada

**`work2.jpg`**

En tu HTML tienes:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="/img/work2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
```

Sin embargo, debería ser:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="img/work2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
```

Debes usar rutas relativas, ya que si usas una barra al comienzo, no estará buscando a partir del directorio raíz del sitio web (fuera del directorio raíz de tu repositorio).

**`Personalizado – 2.svg`**

En la hoja de estilos tienes:

```
background-image: url(/img/Personalizado\ –\ 2.svg);
```

Pero debería ser:

```
background-image: url("../img/Personalizado – 2.svg");
```